# Rails - how many times to write <%end%> after if else condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, syntax

I'm trying to figure out an error message in my production mode. It's referring to a syntax error saying I'm missing keyword end and pointing to a line around about this block of code.

Do I need to write `<% end %>` again? Do I need it once for the `if` and once again for the `else`?

```
<ul id="nav" class="row nopadding cd-side-navigation">
  <% if logged_in_as?(@profile) %>
    <%= render 'profiles/menu_owner', profile: @profile %>   
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'profiles/menu_visitor', profile: @profile %> 
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: i dont see any problem with that code. it's prolly inside partial..

Comment: Maybe you miss some `end` somewhere else above this code, perhaps an `end` for another `if`, and rails think that that `if` block hasn't ended yet until it sees this `if` here and raises an error at wrong place.

Comment: One `end` per `if` by the way, no `end` for `else` or `elsif`, you just need one per `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one <% end %> required per if condition. Please paste in log so we can have closer look.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be fine as it is currently. You only need one `<% end %>` for if/elsif/else block of condition.